# List vm from a host pool in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I try to get a list of vm from a particular host pool. I've search and can't find an answer. I tried the get-azvm command witch do not return the host pool info.

On the other side I can get the host pool info but again not the vm infos ...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "On the other side I can get the host pool info" - how are you retrieving the host pool info?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen From the command Get-AzWvdHostpool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use to get the details of a pool
Get-AzWvdHostPool and Get-AzWvdSessionHost
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.desktopvirtualization/get-azwvdhostpool?view=azps-6.6.0

Comment: Yeah I use this command but cant find a way to get the vm list.

Comment: Hi,Please refer the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.desktopvirtualization/get-azwvdsessionhost?view=azps-6.6.0#examples